# Accessing HTTPS URL from Console Application using C#

Tags: c#, url, ssl, https

I want my application to hit the HTTPS URL specified and download the CSV file from that URL.

I have the following code:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.IO;

namespace httpWebRequest_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var webAddr = "https://SFTP URL/xyz.csv";
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/csv";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
            Stream resStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        }

        AcceptAllCertification aac = new AcceptAllCertification();

        public static RemoteCertificateValidationCallback AcceptAllCertifications { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AcceptAllCertifications.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace httpWebRequest_Test
{
    class AcceptAllCertification
    {
        public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not receiving any error at compile time. But at run time, I am seeing the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

How do I overcome this error?

**Edit 1:**

I tried to access the same URL from the browser and it is showing me the following screen:

[image]

Only after adding exception am I able to continue.

**Edit 2:**

After following answer's by @AndrewSilver and @Übercoder, I am seeing the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required

Thereafter I added `httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;`, which led me to the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Thereafter I added `httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 100;`, which led me to the following error:

> ProtocolViolationException: You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true.  Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse.

**NOTE:** Anyone who improves my answer by providing a solution **without bypassing Certificate validation** will be marked as accepted.

Comment: Have you tried getting the file at the url from a browser? It will most likely fail because the server you are requesting the file from does not have the right certificate required for SSL.

Comment: @Übercoder check my updated question

Comment: This has nothing to do with SFTP, your question is about HTTPS.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Ok. But will I be able to hit the SFTP URL as well with this piece of code ? Or will I have to make a major change using third party solutions ?

Comment: To be more precise, can I access SFTP URL with `HttpWebRequest` ?

Comment: No, you won't. The `HttpWebRequest` is for HTTP, that has nothing to do with SFTP.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Ok. Just for the sake of knowledge, is there any other way that can help me access SFTP URL without using third-party products or any other open-source SFTP Library. I am fully aware that WinSCP does make life easy, But I am looking for some in-built support for SFTP in .Net

Comment: No. There's no native support for SFTP in .NET framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code did the trick for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadCSVFromURL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SplitCSV();
        }

        public static string GetCSV(string url)
        {

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
            (object a, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate b, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain c, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors d) => { return true; };            

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string results = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

            return results;
        }
        public static void SplitCSV()
        {
            List<string> splitted = new List<string>();
            string fileList = GetCSV("URL");
            string[] tempStr;
            tempStr = fileList.Split(',');
            foreach (string item in tempStr)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
                {
                    splitted.Add(item);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone who improves this code by providing a solution **without bypassing Certificate validation** will be marked as accepted.

Comment: This is very useful. Working with rest sharp as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
     new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
```

to this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a,b,c,d) => { return true;};
```

And you can get rid of the other code you have. The problem with your code is that you were referencing the static `AcceptAllCertifications`, which you never set. So it always had a null, which in turn meant that you were not acutally assigning a value to it.

Comment: It is now throwing "The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required." at `var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your certificate is not trusted. You can disable certificate validation or make certificate to be trusted (put certificate under trusted root manually, for example).

see [SSL Certificate Issue - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510316/ssl-certificate-issue-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-valid)

Comment: It is now throwing "The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required." at `var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();` on following the link mentioned in your answer